# Fetch Text of the shipmethod field in Netsuite salesorder record

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Netsuite 1.0 suitescript(AfterSubmit Userevent), salesRecObject.getFieldText("shipmethod") is throwing "SSS_NOT_YET_Supported" exception, while salesRecObject.getFieldValue("shipmethod") gives me "4". I am in need of the Text shown on the UI for ShipVia field (ns internal Id: "shipmethod").

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the shiplabel field?

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, you have two options with this:

1. Switch to SuiteScript 2.0.  The `record.getText()` method works for the `shipmethod` field in version 2.0.
2. If that's not possible for compatibility reasons or whatever, you could do something like:

   ```
   var id = salesRecObject.getFieldValue("internalid");
   var shipText = nlapiLookupField("salesorder", id, "shipmethod", true); //set the final argument to true to get text instead of value
   ```

   Or you could look it up via the shipitem record, rather than the sales order:

   ```
   var shipMethodId = salesRecObj.getValue("shipmethod");
   var shipMethodText = nlapiLookupField("shipitem", shipMethodId, "displayname");
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
function afterSubmit(type){
  nlapiLogExecution('debug','type',type);
  nlapiLogExecution('debug','ship',nlapiGetFieldText('shipmethod'));
}
```